# Android: IntentService used in onDestroy()

Tags: android, intentservice

I am trying to delete a especific registry in a database once the user quits the app. For that issue I call an IntentService whichs runs theorically when the application id destroyed. The problem is that, although this intent does not work as intended and the registry is not deleted. Here is the code if you may help.
IntentService:

```
public class FinIntentService extends IntentService{
    String levelstring = "22";
    int pid;
    static String pids;
    BroadcastReceiver batteryReceiver = null;
    String url = "10.0.0.13";
    private static String url_crear = "http://10.0.0.13/subida/create_candidato.php";
    private static final String url_delete = "http://10.0.0.13/subida/delete_candidato.php";
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    static String device_id = Build.SERIAL;
    static String PDA = device_id.substring(device_id.length() - 6);


            public FinIntentService() {
                    super("FinIntentService");
                }

            @Override
            protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
            {

               int success;



                    try {


                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", Titulacion.getPID()));


                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_delete, "POST", params);


                        Log.d("Delete Product", json.toString());

                        success = json.getInt("success");

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }



        }
```

The Log for example is not reached

Main Activity:

```
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Intent msgIntent = new Intent(Titulacion.this, FinIntentService.class);
    startService(msgIntent);

}
```

I tried to use Asynctask before but I could not get the desired effect when onDestroy. however, in some cases (1 out of 30) the synctask did its task.

Comment: Just guessing.. maybe the application gets destroyed before the intent can be served?

Comment: Yeah, I think so, but is there a solution?

Comment: Why do you do a intentservice to delete a registry in ddbb?

Why dont you delete it directly?

And: why dont you delete it when init the app?

Comment: Well one rough way to deal with it is calling Thread.sleep(X) inside the onDestroy to let your task do your job and preventing the onDestroy to go on for X seconds. Or calling yourthread.join(X) to wait for your thread to end.

Answer (score 0):

Actually [`onDestroy`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) method can not be called.

> [`onDestroy`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) is called only when system is low on resources(memory, cpu time and so on) and makes a decision to kill your activity/application or when somebody calls finish() on your activity.

***If you want to release some resources, you should do that in*** [`onPause()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) ***instead.***

Comment: When you press the Back button onDestroy() gets called on the fly.

Comment: @VittorioJimmyCozzolino, that's why I say "Actually onDestroy method can not be called." :)

Comment: Hi thanks for the explanation, but if I execute it onPause() when the user goes to the next activity the intentService will do its task, I assume.

Comment: @Katherine99 and why you do not remove data in onpause without any Services

Comment: As far as I know, onpause will not solve the situation. IF I start another actvitites I dont want to remove data