# Updating status on server in onDestroy method

Tags: android

I want to **update** status for a user when a user closes his app **directly**.

I tried this but this isn't working :

```
public class ExitService extends IntentService {

private static String TAG = ExitService.class.getSimpleName();

public ExitService() {
    super(TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null) {
        String callNo = intent.getStringExtra("callNo");
        String status = intent.getStringExtra("status");
        updateExitStatus(callNo, status);
    }
}
public void updateExitStatus(final String callNo,final String status){
    StringRequest strReq1= new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Config.UTL_STATUS, new Response.Listener<String>(){
        public void onResponse(String response) {

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("callNo", callNo);
            params.put("status",status);

            Log.e(TAG, "Posting params: " + params.toString());
            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq1);
}
```

}

I have onResume which will update the status to "1"***(taking 1 for online and 0 for offline)***

The app should work in background too, therefore **onStop** and **onPause** ruled out from this equation.

Comment: What's the meaning of "isn't working"?The onDestroy method not called?In fact,you cannot make sure onDestroy gets called when user closes your app.

Comment: BTW,it seems you are doing network request in the main thread,which is a bad idea.Just use a new Thread or something like AsyncTask to do network request.

Comment: @SamMao The api I am using is saving status in database so If I close my app directly then that status doesn't change at all that's how I made sure the code in destroy method didnt worked

Comment: @SamMao What about volley inside onDestroy method?

Comment: I don't know if volley executes network request synchronously or not,just check it yourself and make sure network job is done in new thread. And make sure your update status code get called when user closes your app.I have tested that if user swipe away your app in the recent apps,your onDestroy  and even onStop method may not be called.

Comment: @SamMao No, I have used onStop Method it is working fine but not onDestroy...
onStop has one drawback which i am experiencing i.e this onstop is called even when we move to another activity which I dont want to do because of some reason

Comment: @SamMao I am using **Sahil Mujal** answer and try if it works I'll inform you.

Comment: @SamMao Sahil Code didn't worked status is not getting updated

Comment: @SamMao http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402636/android-intentservice-used-in-ondestroy see answer

Comment: @SamMao is there anything by which we know that app is closed.....the whole app not an activity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this it works for me...

```
 public class App_killed extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("ClearFromRecentService", "Service Started");
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("ClearFromRecentService", "Service Destroyed");
    }

    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Log.e("ClearFromRecentService", "END");
        //Code here call your network call using volley/Asynch task..
        App_close();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Warning: App killed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //stopSelf();
    }

    private void App_close() {
        // Tag used to cancel the request

        String tag_string_req = "close_app";

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_CLOSE_APP, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("close App", "Killed Response: " + response.toString());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("close app", "Killed Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("status", status);
                params.put("mobile", callNo);
                return params;
            }

        };
        // Adding request to request queue
        VollyGlobal.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }
}
```

IN manifest

```
<service
        android:name=".App_killed"
        android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

Now start the service in your MainActivity;

```
startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), App_killed.class));
```

Now in your VolleyGlobal class:

```
    public class VollyGlobal extends Application {

    private static Context context;

    public static final String TAG = VollyGlobal.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static VollyGlobal mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
        VollyGlobal.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return VollyGlobal.context;
    }

    public static synchronized VollyGlobal getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }

    private Request<?> setDefaultRetryPolicy(Request<?> request) {
        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        return request;
    }
}
```

Comment: See my code I am already doing this but some changes you have made  please look my code

Comment: I am calling the intent in onDestroy of that activity

Comment: Suppose status in place of otp that's it

Comment: public void onDestroy(){
        flag=false;
        pulsator.stop();
        callNo= userNo.getText().toString();
        status="0";
        Intent msgIntent = new Intent(this, ExitService.class);
        msgIntent.putExtra("callNo",callNo);
        msgIntent.putExtra("status",status);
        startService(msgIntent);

        super.onDestroy();

    }

Comment: is there anything by which we know that app is closed.....the whole app not an activity ?

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33818406/how-to-detected-if-application-is-closed I am just asking if that's right or not before I start implementing

Comment: implement my code...it will detect the whole app closed  (App_killed)  not in background...and perform network request ..,,just start the service on your launcher activity

Comment: Ok wait I'll try and reply for the results

Comment: but where do I call startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), App_killed.class));? in MainActivity but where in which method I should call it

Comment: Ok you are putting status and mobile in service class but where you are getting it from it is not in service its in mainactivity

Comment: which I was doing in on handle intent

Comment: use shared preference in onTaskRemoved method() of the service

Comment: like:SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences();
        String data1 = (shared.getString(ID, ""));
        String data2 = (shared.getString(TOKEN, ""));
        App_close(data1, data2);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131232/discussion-between-rafsanahmad007-and-sameerkhan1406).

Comment: Good Approach but not working I did exactly what you have told

Comment: Not even getting any toast message the warning which you put I guess the service is not or maybe something wrong in manifest because adding service I was not getting any auto suggestions

Comment: Ok now I am getting this Warning toast text But somethings wrong with the status update

Comment: Got it I am not getting shared preference somethings wrong

Answer (score 0):

Make your call to Server in Intent Service & call that service from onDestroy before super.onDestory().

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        startService(new Intent(this, ServerUpdateIntentService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

And for Intent Service use this link :
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics--mobile-6183

Comment: For more on how to implement intentService, for that you can refer the link provided.

Comment: I'll try this I have already used this type of service before but I give a try and see if it works

Comment: **Sahil Munjal** I guess I dont need Step 4-7 since I just to send and update status on server I am skipping the broadcast receiver method is it okay?

Comment: Yes, just Implement the Service and define it in Manifest and call it from onDestroy.

Comment: <service android:name=".ExitService"></service> in manifest I have to do just this ?

Comment: onDestroy is not going to be called all the time

Comment: **Sahil** I did that same thing calling intent before super onDestroy not working

Comment: is there anything by which we know that app is closed.....the whole app not an activity ?